# Update a table data using max row no record in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I update a table data using max row no record in another table?

My tables are like this:

Table1:

```
|   ID  |   Client  |   Some_Value  |Row_No |
|   1   |   HP      |   123         |   1   |
|   1   |   HP      |   1245        |   2   |
|   1   |   Dell    |   123445      |   3   |
|   2   |   HP      |   111         |   1   |
|   2   |   HP      |   223         |   2   |
|   3   |   Dell    |   34          |   1   |
|   3   |   Dell    |   5563        |   2   |
```

Table2:

```
|   ID  X1      X2       Client |   Some_Value  |
|   1   ABCD    55      |       |
|   1   ad      12      |       |
|   2   asd    1234     |       |
|   2   asd     34      |       |
|   3   asd    2345     |       |
|   3   ads     45      |       |
```

Now I need output as below:

Table2:

```
|   ID  X1    X2    Client  |Some_Value |
|   1   ABCD  55    Dell    |   123445  |
|   1   ad    12    Dell    |   123445  |
|   2   asd   1234  HP      |   223     |
|   2   asd   34    HP      |   223     |
|   3   asd   2345  Dell    |   5563    |
|   3   ads   45    Dell    |   5563    |
```

Comment: The ID in your needed ouput, is it ID from table1 or from table2 ?

Comment: which is the primary and foreign key in your table2?

Comment: Where's your sql statement that you have already tried? What's the common columns between the 2 tables?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ROW_NUMBER` and then join your tables:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Row_No DESC)
    FROM Table1
)
UPDATE t2
SET t2.Some_Value = t1.Some_Value
FROM Table2 t2
INNER JOIN CTE t1
    ON t2.ID = t1.ID
WHERE t1.RN = 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use query as,

```
select t1.ID,t2.X1,t2.X2,t1.Client,t1.Some_value from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on
t1.ID=t2.ID
```